# How do I Install SSRS on an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, reporting-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a SQL database in Azure that I created by publishing via Visual Studio 2013 Lightswith application. I have also installed a Windows 2012 Server vm in the same Azure Subscription. Now I would like to install SSRS on the Windows 2012 Server and generate reports on the data in the SQL server. How do I install the SSRS on the Windows server?

Hi Chris, per your suggestion I was able to install the SQL Server 2014 RTM Enterprise.  One question, (or I should say Question one as I have a few) is this the only version, which pretty expensive in comparison, that has the SSRS? The reality is that I do not even need the database but rather just the reporting functionality as the SQL database already exists in my Azure subscription.  It was created when I published a Visual Studio Lightswitch application to the Azure Website/SQL Database.  Also, when I go into the VM and try to attach to the my original database in Azure I get a message that says my database "**is not a report server database. Please select a SQL Database that contains report server specific tables and stored procedures and try again".**   Does this mean that I have to publish my VS Lightswitch app to the VM I just installed in order to use the SSRS?
Thank you for your response. It is helpful.  Mark

Answer (score 2):

Either install SQL Server and SSRS on the Windows VM from your own setup media using your own license, or create a new SQL Server VM from an Azure Gallery image, such as "SQL Server 2014 RTM Enterprise on Windows Server 2012 R2", which includes SSRS.

Comment: Hi Chris, per your suggestion I was able to install the SQL Server 2014 RTM Enterprise.  One question, is this the only version, which pretty expensive in comparison, that has the SSRS? The reality is that I do not even need the database but rather just the reporting functionality as the SQL database already exists in my Azure subscription.  It was created when I published a Visual Studio Lightswitch application to the Azure Website/SQL Database.

Comment: You can use standard edition as well, that is what i am using now. The express and web edition will not work (at least at this moment). The standard edition is pretty expensive too.  Wish MS could release a reporting service only edition for azure database with a lower price, but seems that is not going to happen. Painful!!!